# Form for searching a CSV ouput results into a table using PHP

Tags: php, csv

I am looking at building a simple app that will display data. The data in the csv is User, User Group, Quarter, Year, Estimated and Actual Costs.

So far I have manged this just ouputs the whole csv.

```
<form id="search" method="get" action="search.php">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="q" size="21" maxlength="120"><input type="submit" value="search" class="button">
        </form>

    <?php
    $row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
            $row++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    ?>
```

I want it to work so that if I have a search the top of the page and submit button for the user to provide their search parameter(s) how would I do it so that say a User or User group was searched it would output it in a table format?

I am thinking possibly separating the html form for best practise.

Comment: Yes. Input from the user needs a form.

Comment: I've had to roll this back to a previous iteration of the question. This isn't a forum - please don't continually update your question as you work through what you're doing. A new problem is a new question.

Comment: Your question has helped me, but as i have a new problem, I will raise a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a form for user input, and the following additions should get you started.

You will probably want to make it a bit more powerful than straightforward exactly equal to matches. For example, a range of years, or greater than X estimated costs.

Stacking up the checks and using `continue` allows users to filter on multiple options.

```
<?php

$searchYear = isset($_GET['year']) ? (int) trim($_GET['year']) : null;
$searchUser = isset($_GET['user']) ? trim($_GET['user']) : null;


// define some constants for the columns in the CSV
// in case someone decides to change the format of it
define('CSV_INDEX_USER', 0); // user is at column 1 (index 0) in the CSV
define('CSV_INDEX_YEAR', 3); // year is at column 4 (index 3) in the CSV

$row = 1;
$output = [];

if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;

        // if the user tried to search on year and it doesn't match, continue skips to the next row
        // casting ensures we compare integers with integers
        if (!empty($searchYear) && (int) $data[CSV_INDEX_YEAR] !== $searchYear) {
            continue;
        }

        // if the user tried to search on user and it doesn't match, skip
        if (!empty($searchUser) && $data[CSV_INDEX_USER] !== $searchUser) {
            continue;
        }

        $output[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

// html

```
<?php if (!empty($output)): ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Your</th>
            <th>Table</th>
            <th>Headings</th>
            <th>Here</th>
        <tr>
        <?php foreach ($output as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$row[0]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[1]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[2]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[3]?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try. I am just looking at displaying the estimates and actual costs for the user it user group.

Comment: @RobertB No worries. If it helped, please consider accepting the answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If the user leaves everything blank in the form the above would return all the records.

Comment: If what's blank? The entire form? Just add some more if statements to eliminate what you need.

Comment: Sounds like that is a fresh question

Comment: So instead of outputting the data with new lines, wrap it in table cells. The additions above demonstrate this. I've separated the logic that creates the output from the logic that produces the HTML.

Comment: Have a go. Look, StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. There's enough above to get you well on your way.

Comment: Thanks I am new to PHP so I am still learning. I will have a go with your code.

Comment: I have split it up but i cant see why it is not showing only results relating to say the user group

Comment: You've not included the constants

Comment: Your form doesn't match the get variables you're checking for. Look up how to process a php form.